# Python equivalent of Ruby's #find_index with lambda?

Tags: python, ruby, list

In Ruby:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[9,3]].find_index {|i| i.include?(3)}
```

Returns `1`, which is the index of the first element in the array containing 3. Is there an equivalent to this in Python? I looked into `List`'s `index` method, but it doesn't seem to take a lambda as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically write something like

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,3],[9,3]]
>>> next(i for i,x in enumerate(a) if 3 in x)
1
```

If not found, you get a `StopIteration` exception, or you can pass a default value to return instead as the second argument:

```
>>> next(i for i,x in enumerate(a) if 99 in x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-5eff54930dd5>", line 1, in <module>
    next(i for i,x in enumerate(a) if 99 in x)
StopIteration

>>> next((i for i,x in enumerate(a) if 99 in x), None)
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there's no direct equivalent function exist in Python.

You can get multiple indice using list comprehension with [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> [i for i, xs in enumerate([[1,2],[2,3],[9,3]]) if 3 in xs]
[1, 2]
```

If you need only the first index, you can use [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with generator expression:

```
>>> next(i for i, xs in enumerate([[1,2],[2,3],[9,3]]) if 3 in xs)
1
>>> next((i for i, xs in enumerate([[1,2],[2,3],[9,3]]) if 999 in xs), 'no-such-object')
'no-such-object'
```